# VSCode WSL - Installing VS Code Server for x64 - FAIL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Can anyone decode the following for me?

WSL was working perfectly on C++ a few weeks back.
Switched to try to run older Python under windows (not WSL) and it seems all twisted up now.
Can't get Win10 nor WSL to run. Keeps trying and failing to update. I re-ran the WSL and updated VSCode on the windows side. I AM behind a proxy but as far as I know, I've update all the files that google searches pointed me at. Pretty frustrated and would appreciate any help there is.

"
Request downloadRequest failed with message: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND update.code.visualstudio.com. Will try to download on WSL side."

"
[2022-02-10 13:51:09.374] Setting up server environment: Looking for /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/server-env-setup. Not found.
[2022-02-10 13:51:09.374] WSL version: 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft Ubuntu-20.04
[2022-02-10 13:51:09.374] Updating VS Code Server to version d6ee99e4c045a6716e5c653d7da8e9ae6f5a8b03
[2022-02-10 13:51:09.374] Removing previous installation...
[2022-02-10 13:51:09.674] Installing VS Code Server for x64 (d6ee99e4c045a6716e5c653d7da8e9ae6f5a8b03)
[2022-02-10 13:51:09.674] Downloading:
[2022-02-10 13:52:43.314] VS Code Server for WSL failed to start. No messages received for 90s
[2022-02-10 13:52:43.314] For help with startup problems, go to
[2022-02-10 13:52:43.314] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
[2022-02-10 13:52:43.328] WSL Daemon exited with code 0

"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% which step fixed it however I was able to proceed after.
Launching C++ project in wsl also tried to update and failed. The difference being that the install button did actually install the wsl server update w/o fail. So that error was gone.

I then launched another VSCode session with the Python project and the cmd terminal. I then had to use this help (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9216#issuecomment-741836058) to adjust the proxy.

I could then proceed to reinstall ipykernel which is what had stopped working and was blocking me.

I'm pretty sure my environments are conflicting with each other. I'm afraid I don't understand VSCode environments well enough and very likely caused this problem for myself.